# How to add custom/normal button on top of navigation bar?

Tags: swift, user-interface, uibutton, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I want to put a custom button in the navigation bar area, but there appear to be limitations for how much you can customize a nav bar item. I want to do a basic button with a rounded square background and custom color for the title and background. Is there a way to layer a normal button on top of the nav bar to get around the lack of customization? I've also tried programmatically changing the bar button item to have the desired traits with no success.

Comment: try using a customised UIButton as the view for the UIBarButton.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom view like that:

```
let customButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
// your customization here
    
// assign your custom view to left/right bar button item  
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)
```